# df.plot.scatter: c and cmap

Tags: python, pandas, colors, scatter

I have a dataframe (nb - the data is dummy data and does not represent what is in the plots):

```
    Index     BGC frequency - Count     Proportion of total BGCs both captured and not captured by antiSMASH - %
  species_a            1                                       2
  species_b            3                                       4
     ...              ...                                     ...
```

I want to make a scatter plot of `BGC frequency - Count` vs `Proportion of total BGCs both captured and not captured by antiSMASH - %`, with points coloured according to the categorical `Index`, and a legend.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import colors
import pandas as pd

colorlist = list(colors.ColorConverter.colors.keys())
captured_df.plot.scatter(x='BGC frequency - Count', 
                         y= 'Proportion of total BGCs both captured and not captured by antiSMASH - %' , 
                          c = colorlist,
                         title = 'BGCs with an antiSMASH region')
```

Gets me close:

[image: Dataframe scatter plot]

But I cant get a legend.  Ideally I'd want something like what is shown [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/visualization.html#scatter-plot), line 69:

[image: desired format of dataframe scatter plot]

But when i tried:

```
df.plot.scatter(x='BGC frequency - Count', y='Proportion of total BGCs both captured and not captured by antiSMASH - %', c=df.index, cmap="viridis", s=50)
```

I get:

```
ValueError: 'c' argument must be a mpl color, a sequence of mpl colors or a sequence of numbers, not Index(...list of index species names...)
```

I'm not sure why this is - I thought `cmap` converts the `c` data into a list of the correct data type?  The link above is explicitly dealing with categorical data -

> If a categorical column is passed to c, then a discrete colorbar will
> be produced

Also please note I dont want a numerical color bar - [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.scatter.html) would not be much use:

[image: bad scatter plot]

Thanks for reading :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to convert the "type" column to categorical (in your case the `Index` column).

For example:

```
d = pd.DataFrame([["a", 1,3], ["b", 3,3], ["b", 2,3], ["a", 5,2]], columns=['type', 'x', 'y'])
d['type'] = pd.Categorical(d['type'])
d.plot.scatter(x='x', y='y', c='type', cmap='inferno')
plt.show()
```

[image]

This should work.

Also it is worth mentioning that this feature is from **Pandas version 1.3.0** ([July 2. 2021](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v1.3.0.html))!

Make sure that you use the appropriate version.